# What is a PS4 bundle from 3rd party?

Tags: ps4, psn, digital-distribution

I'm new to PS4 console gaming. Recently I came through a guy who was selling digital PS4 titles for  very less cheap rates. Like 4-5 games and they call it as game bundles. It almost has all the digital copy top games. He said after payment we'll get a user id and password. Then we have to sign into our PS4 using that ID. Viola! You'll get all the games downloaded directly to your Console. And also mentioned it's lifetime guarantee.

Is it possible?

Comment: Sounds sketchy to me, I wouldn't risk it.  It's possible to resell PS4 activation codes but... there's no real legitimate way to buy or accumulate them in this way that I know of...

Comment: Yeah!! It sounds fishy to me

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> So, my question is. IS IT POSSIBLE?

Yes, it is.

Since you'll be getting an ID and a password, you'd be buying a PSN account (also known as PSN ID).

The guy most likely bought those games for his account, decided he no longer wishes to play, and is now selling you his account containing all the games he purchased.

---

However, I wouldn't buy it.

First of all, selling or buying a PSN ID is against the [**Terms Of Service (TOS)**](https://www.playstation.com/en-us/network/legal/terms-of-service/).

> You may not sell, buy, trade, or transfer your Online ID, Account or any personal access to PSN Services through any means or method, including by use of web sites.

In other words, if Sony ever realizes that the account has been transferred to another person, they could block or delete the account.

Secondly, there are plenty of trust issues associated to buying accounts, such as the account being flagged for online cheating, hacking, or fraud (purchase of games using stolen credit cards, which could lead to even more troubles), the original owner reclaiming ownership after he's "been hacked", and possibly more.

But even if you know and trust the guy, breaching the TOS is something you should definitely avoid, if possible.

Comment: Thank you  and I'm planning to buy those titles which I wanted. I just came through that guy. It was new to me that's the reason I posted the query. But don't know why these folks gave negative points to me.